# Change url without page refresh with all metas and content

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I am trying to change page on click of `a` (anchor tag) without refreshing page. I am using the following script.

```
$('.menu-custom-menu li a').click(function(evt){
    evt.preventDefault();
    var ntext = $(this).attr('href');
    ChangeUrl(ntext, ntext);
});
function ChangeUrl(page, url) {
    if (typeof (history.pushState) != "undefined") {
        var obj = { Page: page, Url: url };
        history.pushState(obj, obj.Page, obj.Url);
    } else {
        alert("Browser does not support HTML5.");
    }
}
```

The above script only change url not fetching page element, I want when I click on a page so whole content should be there, please help me how to do it.

Comment: `pushState` only changes the URL. If you actually want to retrieve the content you will need to make an AJAX request.

Comment: check this may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page

Comment: I don't get it, why don't you just "simply" load the new page if you want to change url, meta and content?

Comment: You can use [Ajaxify](https://4nf.org/)